# Redis, параметр save и снапшоты

Tags: redis

Подскажите: 
1. если параметр save в конфиге Redis установить "" то снапшоты будут выключены?
2. есть ли какая то связь между работой оператора flushdb (очистка базы) и созданием снапошота на диске?